# Using next/font/google when rendering storybook preview causes TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')

Tags: typescript, next.js, storybook

The `next/font/google` imported font is causing `TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')` on Storybook. I have searched and tried everything I could find including:

- Reinstalling Storybook
- Reproducing in a new project
- Using `.variable` instead of `.className`
- Upgrading to Storybook 8
- Overriding `enhanced-resolve` to version 5.10 from 5.11
- Importing the font locally
- Importing the font from `next/fonts/google` directly in `preview.tsx`

File structure:

```
├── .storybook
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── preview.tsx
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── globals.css
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── fonts.ts
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Button
│   │   │   ├── Button.tsx
│   │   │   ├── Button.css
│   │   │   ├── Button.stories.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tailwind.config.js
```

Note: Additionally I tried the default `stories` folder and files that are made automatically by running `npx storybook@latest init`

To reproduce:

1. Run `npx create-next-app@latest`

   - Choose Yes for every question expect the custom aliasing (the last prompt)
2. Run `npx storybook@latest init`
3. Make directory and file `./src/lib/font.ts`
4. Add the following code to `./src/lib/font.ts`:

```
import { Quando } from 'next/font/google'

export const quando = Quando({
  weight: '400',
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-quando',
})
```

5. The `src/app/layout.tsx` should be edited to appear as:

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import { quando } from "@/lib/fonts";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={quando.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

6. Run `npm run dev` the next web app

   - Should see the default next page with the Quando font properly loaded
7. The `.storybook/preview.ts` file should be edited to appear as:

```
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import { quando } from "../src/lib/fonts";

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    Story => (
      <main className={quando.className}>
        <Story />
      </main>
    ),
  ],
};

export default preview;
```

8. Rename `preview.ts` to `preview.tsx` to fix the errors
9. Terminate the storybook process and run `npm run storybook`
10. Get an error on every component that appears as:

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')
Call Stack
 preview.decorators
  main.iframe.bundle.js:51:79
 hookified
  runtime.js:84:10607
 undefined
  runtime.js:100:3256
 undefined
  runtime.js:100:3717
 withOutline
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-bc4dd4.iframe.bundle.js:2986:620
 hookified
  runtime.js:84:10607
 undefined
  runtime.js:100:3256
 undefined
  runtime.js:100:3717
 withMeasure
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-bc4dd4.iframe.bundle.js:2563:14020
 hookified
  runtime.js:84:10607
```

Comment: could you add the folder structure of `storybook/preview.tsx` just to see if the path is correct ..

Comment: @KcH added now! :)

Comment: import looks correct :| .... hope you have gone through this [GH Issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/discussions/22017)

Comment: @KcH I have tried using `.variable` as that post suggests, however I get the same issue and I believe I've already tried importing the font directly there. However I'll confirm a little later on.

Comment: @KcH No luck :( Would you be able to attempt to recreate and see if it's the setup I have or something else going on? If not I understand. Just not even sure how to continue...

Comment: or you can create a codesandbox / stackblitz (preferred) reproducing the issue ....